# How can I do this graph traversal?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

I have a Directed Cyclic graph consisting of node a, b, c, d, e,f g, where ever node is connected to every other node. The edges may be unidirectional or bidirectional. I need to printout a valid order like this for eg. f->a->c->b->e->d->g such that I can reach the end node from the start node. Note that all the nodes must be present in the output list.
Also note that there may be cycles in the graph.

What I came up with:
Basically first we can try to find a start node. If there is a node such that there is no incoming edge to it (there could  be atmost one such node). I may find a start node or may not. Also I will do some preprocessing to find the total number of nodes(lets call it n). Now I will start a DFS from the start node marking nodes as visited when I reach them and counting how many nodes I visited. If I can reach n nodes by this method. I am done. If I hit a node, from which there are no outgoing edges to any unvisited node, I have hit a dead end, and I will just mark that node as unvisited again, reduce the pointer and go to its previous node to try a different route.

This was the case when I find a start node. If I dont find a start node, I will just have to  try this with various nodes.

I have no idea if I am even close to the solution. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Your solution with DFS seems legit, whats the problem? What is the question? I dont understand what means "find start node"? If you have graph, you should have information about all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if there is no incoming edge to a node, it means that node is a start node. You can traverse the graph using this start node. And if this start node can not visit all the n nodes, then there is no solution (as you said that all the nodes must be present in the output list.). This is because if you start with some other nodes, you won't be able to reach this start node.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that if you enter a loop you don't know if and when to exit.

A DFS search in these conditions can easily became a non polynomial task!

Let me introduce a polynomial algorithm for your problem. 
It looks complicated I hope there's room for simplifications.

**Here my suggested solution**

1) For each node construct the table of the nodes it can reach (if a can reach b and c; b can reach d; c can reach e; a can reach b,c,d,e even tough there is not a single pathfrom a passing through all of them).

If no node can reach all the other ones you're done: there is no the path you're looking for.

2) Find loops. That's easy: if a node can reach itself, there is a loop. This should be part of the construction of the table at the previous point.

Once you have find one loop you can shrink it (and its nodes) to the representative node whose ingoing (outgoing) connections are the union of the ingoing (outgoing) connections of the nodes in the loop.

You keep reducing loops until you cannot do any more.

3) At this point you are left with an acyclic graph, If there is a path connecting all nodes, there is a single node connected to all and starting from it you can perform depth first search.

4) 
Write down the path by replacing the traversal of representative nodes with a loop from the entry point of the loop to the exit point.